# How to set boundaries for react native MapView?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, react-android

I have integrated react native map with my latest react native application.In the map i want to set boundaries to the map. The official document suggests the method
    `setMapBoundaries`  but it requires the argument like this `northEast: LatLng, southWest: LatLng`  .

How can i get the values for these arguments.my **mapView** is like this.

```
<MapView
            showsUserLocation
            provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            style={styles.map}
            region={region}
            onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
            setMapBoundaries={}
            onUserLocationChange={this.onUserLocationChange}

        >
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to use is not a `property` or `event`, it's a `method`. So you can't use it there. Check the [documentation](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md) again.

```
setMapBoundaries(northEast: LatLng, southWest: LatLng): void;

export interface LatLng {
   latitude: number;
   longitude: number;
}
```

Try to get the `ref` of the MapView,

```
<MapView
    ref={(ref)=> this.mapRef = ref}
/>
```

and call the method `setMapBoundaries`

`this.mapRef.setMapBoundaries({latitude: 1, longitude: 1},{latitude: 1, longitude: 1})`

Answer (score 1):

### Pass the setMapBoundaries in onRegionChange

```
const onRegionChange = async (region) => {
    const bound = await mapRef.current.getMapBoundaries().then((response) => {
        return response;
     })    -> you can pass this value
        await mapRef.current.setMapBoundaries({latitude: your custom value,longitude: your custom value},{latitude: your custom value,longitude: your custom value}); -> you can pass your custom north-east and south-west coordinate too  
  
  };

<MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        onRegionChange={onRegionChange}
```